# How can I show the css3 transform-origin property in percent?

Tags: css, transform

I have get my transform-origin value:

```
var anchor= $('#clone').css('-moz-transform-origin');
console.log(anchor);
```

the answer is:

```
182.5px 156px
```

but I want it show in percent,like the default

```
"50% 50%"
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these two examples:

This works in Firefox 11. It just displays the value as percentages:

[Firefox (11) Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hyBpk/)

This one works for example in the current Chromium, I do the formatting from Pixels to Percentages myself:

[Chromium Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hyBpk/2/)